# Op-amp circuit with feedback: does the polarity matter?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Suppose we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXlmxJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does the polarity of the op-amp (= which terminal is the inverting and the non-inverting input) affect \$U_o\$? Taking the usual analysis (see below) into consideration it seems like it doesn't matter. This makes no sense to me, because op-amps act as comparators. Can someone please give me an intuitive explanation of why this happens, if it is true? Also, is there any case that the polarity matters when we have feedback?

Analyzing the circuit: suppose we want to find \$\frac{U_o}{U_s}\$:

- Voltage law from GND,\$U_s\$ through the inverting terminal(=GND, virtual short): \$-U_s+i_1R_1=0 \Rightarrow U_s=i_1R_1\$ (1)
- Voltage law from inverting terminal(=GND, virtual short) through \$U_o\$: \$i_2R_2+U_o=0 \Rightarrow U_o=-i_2R_2\$ (2)
- Current law for the node next to inverting terminal: \$i_1=i_2\$ (3)

(1), (2), (3) \$\Rightarrow \frac{U_o}{U_s}=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$.

Comment: You can't apply the voltage law like that without assuming negative feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not correct to say a opamps are designed to work like comparators. They are two different components and though fundamentally similar, they are not the same.

Positive feedback tends to allow op-amp behave like a comparator with hysteresis or Schmitt triggers. That said, an op-amp has so much open loop gain that it will behave like a comparator if there is no feedback of any kind, just one that is slow because it is not optimized to work in saturation.

The polarity of the inputs always matters regardless of circuit. When the voltage at the non-inverting input is higher than the voltage at the inverting input, the op-amp output rises. When the inverting input is higher than the non-inverting input, the output falls.

This means that if you connect output to noninverting input, you get positive feedback. The output reinforced the input and the input reinforces the output causing it to climb without limit and saturate unless it is held in check by negative feedback elsewhere. This is a comparator-like operation.

This also means that if you connect output to inverting input, you have negative feedback. The output opposes the input and the op-amp finds an equilibrium between the two. This is how an op-amp is optimized to work (in the linear region, and not in saturation).

The ENTIRE reason the "virtual ground" exists is precisely because negative feedback. The negative feedback causes the output to drive the inverting terminal to be equal to the non-inverting terminal (which is tied to ground). If you reverse the input polarity then you can no longer assume that the the inverting and noninverting terminals are equal because there is no longer any negative feedback to produce a virtual ground.

Comment: Edited my question,  does the polarity affect \$U_o\$ (with feedback only)?

Comment: @BramFran That doesn't change my answer. It's already answered in the second paragraph. The ENTIRE reason the "virtual ground" exists is precisely because negative feedback. The negative feedback causes the output to drive the inverting terminal to be equal to the non-inverting terminal (which is tied to ground). If you reverse the input polarity then you can no longer assume that the the inverting and noninverting terminals are equal because there is no longer any negative feedback to produce a virtual ground.

Comment: That's it! We can assume virtual ground only because we have negative feedback. I think I got it now...

Comment: _"unrestrained positive feedback makes the op-amp behave like a comparator"_ I guess you're thinking about a Schmitt trigger, which is a _kind_ of comparator, but in general you don't need to have feedback (positive or negative) to get a comparator - simply have the op amp work in open loop.

Comment: @edmz Hmmm, that's true. They have such high open-loop gain that you don't need positive feedback to make it saturate. I will modify it to mention things like comparators with hysteresis and schmitt triggers.